# How to Create a CancellationTokenSource that will be in the canceled state when ALL of the source tokens are in the canceled state

Tags: c#

My client connects to multiple servers (using SignalR) and have a CancellationTokenSource for each that gets cancelled when the connection breaks etc

In some function I want to wait (ie `await Task.Delay(1000, token)`) but I want the delay to exit if ALL of the connection tokens are in the canceled state - that is there is not even one connected server.

How to achieve that ? `CancellationTokenSource` provides `CreateLinkedTokenSource` but the produced token will be in the canceled state when *any* of the source tokens are in the canceled state not *all*

Comment: Can you just await triggered tasks?, task will be completed when it completes or being cancelled by cancellation token. `Task.WhenAll(allTasks)`

Comment: What I have are CancellationTokenSource s created when a connection is established and canceled if the connection breaks, I am not sure what you suggest as there are no multiple tasks here ?

Comment: The question is too broad, given the large number of ways one might implement your exact specification. That said, the specification itself is suspect. You seem to be misusing cancel token. If you are using the TPL to represent a "connection" (network connection?), then a much more suitable object to do that would be `Task`, not `CancellationToken`. Especially if this is for networking code, since in the TPL paradigm, you have a `Task` representing an `async` method that has a loop reading from the network, which will be completed when that loop terminates for whatever reason.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I'll have to think about this, what I have are SignalR connections created with `HubConnectionBuilder` where I can add a `Closed` event (where I cancel a token), there may be a way to wrap all that in a Task .. not sure

Comment: If you're creating a `CancellationTokenSource` for each connection to represent when it is closed, consider using `TaskCompletionSource` instead. It's a better representation, since the connection is _completed_ rather than cancelled, and it means you can use `Task.WhenAny` and `Task.WhenAll`

Answer (score 1):

I think this solution could work - although this isn't usually how a cancellation token is supposed to be used. I haven't verified the dispose logic, so you may want to double check that.

```
var tokens = ...;
var all = new CancellationTokenSource();
void OnCancel()
{
    if (tokens.All(token => token.IsCancellationRequested))
        all.Cancel();
}

var registrations = new List<CancellationTokenRegistration>();
foreach (var token in tokens)
    registrations.Add(token.Register(OnCancel));

all.Register(() =>
{
    foreach (var registration in registrations)
        registration.Dispose();
});

// Use the token
```

Oh, one more thing - I'm not sure how this will behave if all of the tokens are already cancelled when you register the callbacks.